# how to use foreign key for auto-incremented records?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student`;  
 CREATE TABLE `student` (  
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `student_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=901840505 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `grades`;  
 CREATE TABLE `grades` (  
  `grade_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `grade` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`grade_id`),  
  KEY `stdgrd_idx` (`student_id`),  
  CONSTRAINT `stdgrd` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student`   (`student_id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1641 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have created two tables `student` and `grade`. In order to send the auto-incremented values of`student_id` to `grade`(student_id) table I established a foreign key between those two records as follows:

```
CONSTRAINT `stdgrd` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student`
(`student_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

My question is when I insert values into `student_name` record in the `student` table the `student(student_id)` is auto-incremented so I want the auto-incremented value to be sent to `grade(student_id)` 
but the `grade` table is not taking the value in. I already tried with the help of questions posted in `stackoverflow` but I couldn't make it. Please can anyone help out with this issue??

Comment: there's no way that adding  a record to a child table would trigger an auto_increment in a parent table...

Comment: Do you think is there any other way that can solve my issue?

Comment: foreign keys don't "send" anything anywhere. they just enforce a parent/child relationship and disallow orphaned records. you would first have to insert (create) a `student` record, causing mysql to create an ID for you. you get that ID with `last_insert_id()`, and use it for inserts into the grades table.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please send me a query associated with it?

Comment: `inert into students ...` then `select last_insert_id()`, then `insert into grades ... values ($last_insert_id, ...)`

Comment: Sir I tried this queries but it is just inserting auto-incremented value to the last used column.                                                                 insert into student(student_name) values('ramgopal');
select last_insert_id();
insert into grades(student_id,grade) values(last_insert_id(),'A');
insert into class(semester,day,time)  values('spring 2015','tuesday','12');
select last_insert_id();
insert into grades(class_id) values(last_insert_id());                                               In `grade` table I got `grade_id`,`class_id`,`student_id` and grade records.

Comment: yes, because the function is **LAST** insert_id(). as soon as you do another insert, you get the insert_id() of THAT insert. you need to preserve the value created from your `student` insert.

Comment: where should I preserve it and how??

Comment: Sir please reply me when u have time I'm in dire need of your help. I hope you understand.

Comment: It started working with the help of the below queries:                      insert into student(student_name) values('sai');
select last_insert_id();
set @last_insert_id=last_insert_id();
insert into class(semester,day,time) values('spring 2015','Thursday','6pm');
select last_insert_id();
set @g=last_insert_id();
insert into grades(student_id,class_id,grade) values (@last_insert_id,@g,'E');                                                          Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Foreign Key relationship is only intended to validate the content of the child column. There is no automatic transfer of data. Inserting into `student` and thus generating the `student_id` auto_inc value will have no immediate impact on the `grades` table. That merely creates a `student_id` value that is now an acceptable content for the `grades`.`student_id` column.

Comment: Is there any other way to trigger that auto-incremented value to `grade` table.

Comment: You could use a stored procedure to accomplish that, but I would question the use case. The relationship between `student` and `grades` is 1-to-many, so I don't think "sending" that auto_inc would be meaningful? How do you plan to populate the `grade` column of `grades`? Surely a student has many grades? Why would the creation of a student imply the creation of a grade?

Comment: Its just for a single course so obviously he will be having only one grade.

Comment: Then make `grade` a column in `students`. If your data is 1-to-1 you don't need two tables.

Comment: Sir actually I have assigned a task to establish a relation between a two tables.

Comment: Not only this I got many relations to create between two tables but initially I would like to know how this works so later on I can go ahead with the rest of the operation.

Comment: I wish you the best of luck, Sir. All I can say is that you are attempting something very much outside the standard use cases of MySQL. I advise against your intended course of action.

Comment: I did it with the help of last_insert_id query.